# bash - Como prevenir execução de código malicioso via entrada?

Tags: segurança, bash, shell, shell-script

Eu possuo um script (`script.sh`) que recebe uma *variável de ambiente*:

```
echo $MINHAVARIAVEL
```

Mas ao chamá-lo via terminal, percebi que posso passar comandos por essa variável, e estes comandos são executados sem verificações ao estilo *sql injection*. Exemplo:

```
home$ MINHAVARIAVEL=$(rm -rf /etc) script.sh
```

Ao invés de tratar a variável como uma string, o meu script trataria ela como um comando, injetaria ela na instrução, e executaria a mesma, abrindo precedentes para furos de segurança.

Como eu evito a execução de código malicioso em variáveis de ambiente? Ou ainda: Como eu forço minha variável de ambiente a ser interpretada apenas como uma "string" inofensiva?

Comment: Esse código da "injeção" já ocorre no momento da atribuição. Fazer a expansão da variável não vai executar o `rm -rf`

Comment: pois é. quando você coloca um comando entre `$()` ele é executado imediatamente. nesse caso aí, `$MINHAVARIAVEL` contém o resultado do `rm`, e é isso que é passado para o enironment do script. Executar uma string como comando é papel do `eval` (com todos os riscos inerentes ao seu uso)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A entrada de dados proposta na pergunta provoca a execução do código antes de passar a variável para o script.

O uso de subshell `$()` executa o comando *imediatamente* e substitui seu resultado na string:

```
nunks@yokoi:~$ TESTE="Diretorio atual: $(pwd)"
nunks@yokoi:~$ echo $TESTE
Diretorio atual: /home/nunks
```

Sendo assim, a execução proposta está primeiro removendo o /etc e depois chamado o script. Não é o script que executa o código malicioso, é a própria atribuição de `$MINHAVARIVEL` feita pelo usuário.

Para fazer com que o script cause essa execução maliciosa, você precisaria fazer (mal-)uso do `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script.sh
eval $MINHAVARIAVEL;
```

> **~$** MINHAVARIAVEL='rm -rf /etc' ./script.sh

---

**Aviso obrigatório sobre o uso de `eval`**

Ressalto aqui que, **via de regra**, não se deve usar `eval` para nada. O exemplo acima é justamente um caso em que seu uso representa uma falha de segurança. É praticamente impossível garantir a validade de todos os inputs (usuários maliciosos tendem a ser bastante espertos), sendo muito melhor interpretar a entrada de dados do usuário e definir o que será executado dentro do script. **É algo inerentemente inseguro permitir que o usuário execute comandos de sistema operacional dentro de seu script**.

---

**Uso de substituição de comando `$(comando)` ou `` `comando` ``**

A abertura de uma subshell dentro dos parênteses `$(comando)` ou acentos graves `` `comando` `` é chamada pelo bash de [substituição de comando](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html): o comando em questão é avaliado primeiro e seu retorno é passado para o comando "de fora", sendo muito útil para atribuir variáveis dinamicamente.

É importante frisar que esse tipo de expansão **funciona como `eval`, devendo ser tratado com o mesmo cuidado**. A execução maliciosa acima também pode ser provocada com substituições:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script.sh
echo $($MINHAVARIAVEL);
```

> **~$** MINHAVARIAVEL='rm -rf /etc' ./script.sh

---

**Uso de substituição de processo `<(comando)` e `>(comando)`**

O bash também proporciona a [substituição de processos](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), possibilitando que eles funcionem como "arquivos" através da criação dinâmica de FIFOs ou arquivos "numerados" no /dev/fd. Isso é muito prático para, por exemplo, se trabalhar com a saída de pipelines complexos sem a necessidade de antes armazená-los em arquivo.

A substituição inteira é utilizada como se fosse um arquivo, sendo que comando passado entre parênteses é avaliado e executado como nas substituições de comando mencionadas acima, mas sua saída é enviada para um arquivo temporário ou FIFO para ser lida imediatamente pelo processo que o chamou. Sendo assim, **também funciona como `eval` e também deve ser utilizado com cuidado**. Exemplo da mesma execução maliciosa supracitada, agora com substituição de processo:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script.sh
cat <($MINHAVARIAVEL);
```

> **~$** MINHAVARIAVEL='rm -rf /etc' ./script.sh

---

## Portanto...

Há mais de uma forma de se executar código contido em variáveis no bash, e nenhuma delas deve ser utilizada sem que se tenha controle do que há dentro da variável em questão. São todas tão perigosas quanto o `eval`.

Isso serve sobretudo como aviso de que **o input do usuário não deve nunca ser utilizado como dado**, e deve ser sempre verificado. Defina de maneira estrita o "formato" ou "tipo" dos dados de input e, antes de mais nada, verifique se eles se enquadram dentro do esperado.

**Verificação de dados de entrada**

Dito isso, é sempe importante sanear as entradas de dados para evitar não só o uso malicioso, mas também muitos bugs inerentes à criatividade do usuário na escolha dos dados a passar para o script.

O bash oferece [diversos tipos de teste](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) para facilitar a identificação de variáveis, como por exemplo o teste para saber se ela aponta para um caminho de arquivo existente (`-a`):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -a $MINHAVARIAVEL ]]; then
  echo MINHAVARIAVEL deve ser um arquivo!;
  exit 1;
fi;
```

Para casos em que o formato da string passada é conhecido e estrito, eu costumo utilizar expressões regulares. Exemplo com string de data:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! $ANOMESDIA =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
  #sei que a regex acima e bastante simploria para teste de data,
  #trata-se de mero exemplo
  echo O formato de ANOMESDIA deve ser AAAA-MM-DD!;
  exit 1;
fi;
```

Visando facilitar a vida do usuário final, meus scripts tendem a conter uma montanha de testes antes de começar a execução de verdade, buscando garantir que os dados de entrada sejam inseridos com formato definido de modo tão estrito quanto for possível. A cada teste em falso ofereço uma mensagem explicativa de erro e uma ajuda básica do comando, para depois terminar com código de erro:

```
#!/bin/bash
#testaidade.sh

help() {
  echo
  echo Ajuda:
  echo Passe sua idade para script!;
  echo Exemplo: $0 22;
}
IDADE=$1;

if [[ -z $IDADE ]]; then #$IDADE está vazia
  help;
  exit 1;
fi;
if [[ ! $IDADE =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo Sua idade deve ser um valor numérico.;
  help;
  exit 1;
fi;
echo Idade testada. O valor informado foi $IDADE;
```

Assim, você pode manipular as informações em seu script sem qualquer preocupação extra quanto à integridade das entradas informadas pelo usuário.

Comment: Então é "impossível" o usuário passar um código malicioso via input que acabe sendo executado, correto? A não ser que eu use `eval` (ou outro comando de execução explícito no input), eu estou protegido e posso lidar com o input sem medo de código injetado no meu script?

Comment: Do jeito que você colocou na pergunta o código malicioso é executado sim, mas no momento da atribuição da variável, na subshell de expansão de comando $(), e não pelo script.
Dito isso, desde que o seu script não saia executando strings de input sem antes verifica-las, você pode ficar tranquilo. Está protegido desde que não pule do avião sem verificar se está usando paraquedas, haha.